# scraping interactive map with iframe target element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the coordinates of bikeshare stations [(see the map in the bottom of the page)](https://bikeitau.com.br/sao-paulo/), that is placed in iframe `iframe[src*='looker.com/embed/']`

But when I open the code of the page, I cannot see anything related to the coordinates inside the map, so I don't even have any code to share. Is there any way to get the coordinates from the map via `Selenium` or `HttpClient`?

Comment: Instead of coordinates it shows me the _Name_ and _Address_ even manually.

Comment: [Please don't repost questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/248627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is a bit tricky, as far as map that you are trying to parse doesn't contain coordinates, however, you can get them by parsing response from the map `GET` request.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import json

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--headless")
caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://bikeitau.com.br/sao-paulo/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='looker.com/embed/'")))
time.sleep(5)
logs = driver.get_log("performance")

target_url = "/query?querySource=look_query"

for log in logs:
    message = log["message"]
    if "Network.responseReceived" in message:
        params = json.loads(message)["message"].get("params")
        if params:
            response = params.get("response")
            if response:
                if response and target_url in response["url"]:
                    body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getResponseBody', {'requestId': params["requestId"]})
                    body_json = json.loads(body['body'])['data']
                    for address_object in body_json:
                        print(address_object['obt_stations.location']['value'])
```

1. You enable network tab spy on Selenium
2. Needed response has `/query?querySource=look_query` in query
3. You loop all responses you got and get their `message`
4. You loop through responses and find one which has needed query
5. You get response body
6. You get body `data` object
7. You get location `obt_stations.location` object value from data

Also you can get any needed object by investigating variable `body_json`.

Comment: thank you for the answer! could you also help with a similar case - there's another interactive map with the same stations, what do I change in your code to scrape the locations as well? https://bikesharemap.com/saopaulo/#/13/-46.688/-23.5749/

Comment: @barneystinson2 in 2nd case needed url endpoint contains `/bikesapi/systems_js.php`. whole link is `https://gladys.geog.ucl.ac.uk/bikesapi/systems_js.php?zoom=13&lon=-46.688&lat=-23.5749`. You can go through response, objects and get `lon` snd `lat` props inside

Comment: where should I paste these ```/bikesapi/systems_js.php``` and ```https://gladys.geog.ucl.ac.uk/bikesapi/systems_js.php?zoom=13&lon=-46.688&lat=-23.5749```?

Comment: when I insert the whole link in ```target_url```, I get an error in line ```WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='looker.com/embed/'")))```

Comment: This is a completely different resource with different response :) It needs separate script. Logic is similar, but selectors / links / json structure is different.

Comment: I understand that selectors, links and json structure are different in this case, but anyway, how to get the respose? how to choose the selector and what should I do with the link that you sent earlier? I really don't have any experience in scraping, all I ever did was to scrape a simple spreadsheet with bs4

Comment: You should choose any selector that would tell you that map is rendered (and that would be guarantee that needed request is come. 
Needed request you can see in Network tab in Developer console - just open console, network tab and load your site

Comment: When you will find needed request, open Preview tab of it, so you will see response. Look at it's structure, so you will know, what is json path to needed props

Comment: And then you just loop through data and get define your json structure loop instead of lines `for address_object in body_json:
                        print(address_object['obt_stations.location']['value'])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254926/discussion-between-barney-stinson-2-and-yaroslavm).

Comment: You need just adopt this script for another case ) only 3 params should be changed - selector for rendered condition, request link that you observed, logic that related to your new JSON structure after getting JSON body